# Is vigilance correlated to intelligence?

Tags: iq-intelligence, correlation

I found this study

https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01447089

but it was about 'at-risk' children, and spoke of vigilance as something to do with paying attention. I'm thinking of vigilance in terms of keeping clean, hygiene, wound dressing, sanitation, attention to details, not letting things slip through the cracks, fastidiousness, on-the-ball, things like that.

Comment: Probably get better answers at [CogSci](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/).  I would say that vigilance is one of the constituents of intelligence, in that intelligence is a measure of the ability to optimize changes to conditions for a certain difference of state.  That's not the only useful understanding of intelligence, though.